# Object variable or With block variable not set issue

Tags: excel, vba, object

I'm having issues with a loop performing multiple if-conditionals. What im doing is 
1. Define ranges and cells for "what to look for and where to look from". 
2. Issue part: My If should be three-leveled. 
- If x is true, do things, else if2
- If2 is true, do things, else if3
- if3 is true, do things

Loop next x

For some reason it goes fine for a couple of times but then it gives me Object variable or With block variable not set. How do i fix this..?

The error is on line:

`If Not cl Is Nothing And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x + 1, 7) = cl.Offset(0, -4) Then`

```
 Sub Question()


Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim lr3 As Long
Dim lr4 As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long, n As Integer
Dim arr As Variant, arr2 As Variant
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim rng2 As Range, c2 As Range


    n = 20 'Start row of Sheet1
    m = 20 'Start row of Sheet2
    o = 20 'Start row of Sheet3

    'Fill the array for a loop in memory
    With Blad6

        lr1 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:A" & lr1 + 1)
        lr3 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arr2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:A" & lr1 + 1)

    End With


    'Get the range to look in
    With Sheet1
        lr2 = Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("H2:H" & lr2)
    End With


    With Blad6
    'Loop over the array and perform the search

    For x = 1 To UBound(arr)

       Set cl = rng.Find(arr(x, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cl Is Nothing And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x + 1, 7) = cl.Offset(0, -4) Then
            'Things happen here

                n = n + 1

            Else



            If Not cl Is Nothing And Worksheets("").Cells(x + 1, 7) <> cl.Offset(0, -4) And cl.Offset(0, -4) <> 0 And cl.Offset(0, -5) > Worksheets("").Cells(x + 1, 3) Then
           'Things happen here
                m = m + 1

            Else

            If cl Is Nothing Then

              'Things happen here

                o = o + 1

        End If
        End If
        End If

    Next

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic



End Sub
```

Comment: Oh im sorry, added it to the original and the error is on line  

If Not cl Is Nothing And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x + 1, 7) = cl.Offset(0, -4) Then

Comment: None of your with statements make sense since you not using them.

Answer (score 0):

VBA evaluates both sides of the `AND` statement, so if cl is nothing, it still tries to use it on the second part (giving you an error)...

You need to nest 2 If's instead like this

```
If Not cl Is Nothing 
  If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x + 1, 7) = cl.Offset(0, -4) Then
    ' do stuff here if cl is valid and offset condition is met
  Else
    ' do stuff if cl is valid but does not meet the offset condition 
  End If
Else
    ' do something when cl is nothing 
    ' could be the same thing as in above Else
    ' assuming cl is not involved in the operation
End If
```

If you were using VB.NET then you could use `AndAlso` instead and structure it more like you have it, but you aren't, so you can't.

Comment: Okay, i changed it to a nested If. However i have a pretty newbie problem here, because my If statements are not moving as i want them to. If i the first "if-sentence is false, i want it to move to "else" or if the second sentence is false, i want it to move to "else". So if either is false, it should move to the same else function. Im unable to do this for some reason...

Comment: I updated the answer for you. Is that what you meant?